# Translation of "someone will remind you of the danger"

Tags: english-to-german, word-choice

(Meaning "will make you remember of the danger", "will make you think about the danger" and so on).

My attempt:

> Jemand wird dich an die Gefahr erinnern

However I'm almost sure that it's not a good translation (or it's even wrong, or means something else), but I can't find any better alternatives. The dicionary gives

```
to remind sb about sth     jdn an etw (akk) erinnern
```

Is there a better translation?

Comment: Your translation is perfectly fine.

Comment: I'd prefer `Es wird dich jemand an die Gefahr erinnern`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auch : Es wird dich jemand an die Gefahr gemahnen. (geh)

Comment: JFTR: Gemahnen is a lot less commonly used than erinnern.

Comment: Wenn schon gemahnen, dann bitte mit Genitiv: "Es wird dich jemand der Gefahr gemahnen".